# Why can't we paranethsize a matrix mutliplication in this way?

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose we have four matrices. My instructor told me that there are 5 ways to paranthesize those matrices. However, none of those 5 ways included this way:

> (A_1) * (A_2) * (A_3) * (A_4)

Does anyone know why that this isn't included?

Answer (score 0):

"Parenthesizing" means specifying the order of the 3 matrix multiplications. Your parenthesization does not do that.

Comment: Why does it have to be 3 matrix multiplications?

Comment: @echo: You start with one matrix. The first multiplication combines with the next matrix. Then there are two additional multiplications to take into account the remaining two matrices. Makes a total of three multiplications.